# Border spacing between the columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns in a row, each of which has the class **col-xs-4** and so they cover up the entire row. Now I need to add `border` for each of these columns and I don't want them to overlap.

Currently, am using `border` but there's no spacing between the columns.I want some space between the borders of these columns so they look like they are separated from each other.

I can't use offset because the columns start stacking vertically.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show what you did

Comment: @Fel  This is how it looks now. I want some spacin g betweent the columns http://tinypic.com/r/r7vpeh/8

Comment: @Simon This is how it looks now. http://tinypic.com/r/r7vpeh/8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question as-is was very clear and good but please avoid statements like *thanks*, *I am new* etc. They are not really required (considered as fluff) and would almost always be edited out. There is no need to mention the library names in title because it is part of the tags. Finally while adding tags, hover on the tag and see the usage details. For example, the bootstrap tag (I have removed) is not applicable here because it is meant for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use paddings and a child div

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  padding: 16px;
}
.col-xs-4 > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<row>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste necessitatibus, sapiente vitae ullam exercitationem debitis quos quod, consequatur nobis cumque aut totam neque provident tempore recusandae vel quis suscipit eum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste necessitatibus, sapiente vitae ullam exercitationem debitis quos quod, consequatur nobis cumque aut totam neque provident tempore recusandae vel quis suscipit eum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste necessitatibus, sapiente vitae ullam exercitationem debitis quos quod, consequatur nobis cumque aut totam neque provident tempore recusandae vel quis suscipit eum.
    </div>
  </div>
</row>
```

Comment: Hi Mehdi. It added borders to each div inside the column. looks messy. I want to know if i can reduce the width of columns and add border.

Comment: Please make me a fiddle. But adding margins or change width of bootstrap's columns can break your layout and will be difficult to maintain (that's why i put a div inside the columns).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reducing the width of col-xs-4 and added a border.